# OpenMP - Parallel region within master directive

Tags: c++, parallel-processing, openmp

I want to declare a parallel for within a master region, like this:

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    #pragma omp master
    {
        *many functions...*

        #pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i = 0; i < x; ++i){
            a += i;
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example code, I have hundreds of functions that I don't want to manually add the master clause in each of them, but is this possible to do? Or is there any other way to do what I want?

Answer (score 3):

```
#pragma omp parallel
{
    //mater only
    #pragma omp master  
    {
       *many functions...*
    }
    //full team: just for not parallel for
    #pragma omp for 
    for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i){
        a += i;
    }
}
```

Just declare the for outside of the mater.

Or just do the sequential actions out side of the parallel section al together

```
    *many functions...*

#pragma omp parallel for 
for(int i = 0; i < x; ++i){
    a += i;
}
```